# Replacing @ManagedBean(eager=true) in JSF22

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, eager

I am looking for a solution to replace the `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` annotation in JSF 2.2.

I took good note of proposals [such as](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.fr/2013/02/eager-cdi-beans.html) which allow the execution of code at application start up.

I need however to access the `FacesContext`, so this solution does not work : `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is still null at this time.

I tried to find alternatives to `AfterDeploymentValidation` in SPI, but found nothing.

As developpers of DeltaSpike do not seem to plan to implement a substitution to [`@ManagedBean(eager=true)`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-453) and as OmiFaces does not yet support this kind of solution, [see](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/18). I am sending a message in a bottle.

For the time being, I just access the `@ManagedScoped(eager=true)` bean, transformed into a `@Named`, in my webapp common xhtml header, but it is kind of ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution for a JSF application with DeltaSpike is the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean
{
    public void init(@Observes PostConstructApplicationEvent event)
    {
        // init here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thank you for your proposal, but it does not work. The method is never called, with both DeltaSpike versions 0.6 and 0.7-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Well, in fact, it works. Part of my problem was that the wrong servlet version was used in web.xml. Thx again !

Comment: I found another use/case where it is not enough. When using @Observes PostConstructApplicationEvent, the init call is not enclosed in the various filtered configured in web.xml. So, in some cases, all the inits I need are not performed...

Answer (score 3):

Since [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 1.8, there's a CDI compatible [`@Eager`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/cdi/Eager.html) which not only works on `@Named @ApplicationScoped`, but als on CDI's `@SessionScoped` and `@RequestScoped` and OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`. See also the [blog entry](http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2014/06/omnifaces-18-released.html) and the [showcase example](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Eager).

You can use it either with `@Eager @ApplicationScoped`:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Eager;

@Named
@Eager
@ApplicationScoped
public class Bean {
    // ...
}
```

or with [`@Startup`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/cdi/Startup.html), which is a stereotype for `@Eager @ApplicationScoped`:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.Startup;

@Named
@Startup
public class Bean {
    // ...
}
```