# How to make a CDI bean eagerly initialized in Quarkus app

Tags: quarkus, cdi, eager-loading

There is the project with quarkus 1.2.1 + jakarta cdi 2.0.2.
I've added a listener for SQS messages.
The problem is that all the beans are created lazily by default that is obviously not suitable for the listener. How to make this specific bean being initialized on application startup?
Unfortunately there is not @StartUp in this jakarta version. Are there any ways to do it?

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-universe-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import java.util.Map;

@ApplicationScoped
@Named("customListener")
public class CustomListener implements MessageListener {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomListener.class);
    private final CustomService customService;

    @Inject
    public CustomListener(
            @Named("customService") CustomService  customService) {
        this.customService = customService;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        final SQSTextMessage sqsMessage = (SQSTextMessage) message;
        //bla bla bla
    }
}
```

Comment: In case you're interested in answer to "How to make a CDI bean eagerly initialized in Servlet app" head to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468317 and "How to make a CDI bean eagerly initialized in Faces app" head to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24077486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDI does not provide an out-of-the-box way to "eagerly" initialize beans.

Quarkus has a specialized [`@Startup` annotation (`quarkus.io`)](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#startup_annotation) since version `1.3.0.Final` to achieve what we want.

With CDI 4.0, the [`Startup` event (`jakarta.ee`)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/event/startup) was introduced. With this, we can enforce the creation of beans by observing the event from within the bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named("customListener")
public class CustomListener ... {
    ...
    public void eagerInit(@Observes Startup unused) {
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Thanks to [Ladislav Thon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742081/ladicek), [who provided the code sample for CDI 4.0 in zulip (`quarkusio.zulipchat.com`)](https://quarkusio.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/187030-users/topic/.E2.9C.94.20Jakarta.20CDI.20-.3E.20initialize.20bean.20eagerly/near/406331613).

Comment: So it looks likethere are no ways to do it without updating quarkus version(to update CDI to 4.0)

Comment: Not sure since when Quarkus' `@Startup` is around, but I *think* it should be available since quarkus `1.x`. Anyway, I would recommend an upgrade anyway sincd `1.x` is out of support. I would recommend to upgrade to at least  `3.2.x` (LTS) or `2.16.x` (if no upgrade to quarkus `3.x`/`jakarta` is possible).

Comment: Update: Quarkus' `@Startup` is available since quarkus `1.3.0.Final`. So a minor version upgrade would be necessary to use this feature.

Comment: However, CDI does not provide a way to "eagerly" initialize beans, Quarkus does. More information at: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi#applicationscoped-and-singleton-look-very-similar-which-one-should-i-choose-for-my-quarkus-application

Comment: @zforgo careful. The `@Singleton` bean is created eagerly *when injected*. If the bean is not injected, it is not created.

Comment: Quarkus has had the `StartupEvent` since very early on, it was definitely there in 1.0. So if you have Quarkus 1.2.1, you can observe [Quarkus-specific] `StartupEvent` (just like you can observe [CDI-standard] `Startup` since CDI 4.0). But more importantly, you _really_ should upgrade :-)